# File upload from Azure App Service to Azure Function fails, but not every time

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

We are using a React web app as frontend and Azure Function as backend. The user can upload a file through our frontend. The frontend then sends the file via a REST call to an Azure Function.

I observed a strange behaviour which I can't explain: I open the web app and upload a file which is 2 MB big. I trigger the REST call via button click. Nothing happens. After ~ 2,1 minutes the call stops without a response received.

When I open the web app and upload a file which is very small (~ 120 kb). I trigger the REST call via button click. The response is 200 -ok after about 20 seconds. Then I upload the same file from before (2MB big) and trigger the rest call, I receive a response in < 30 seconds with status code 200 -ok. So in general the backend can handle the file size.

Why is this happening?

Could a possible reason be azure functions cold start?

No error is present in Azure diagnostic tools.

Comment: What response you are getting when it is fail ? Also some sample code can be more useful. Are you using dotnet core 3 or v3 function or dotnet-isolated with v3.

Comment: When I use Edge browser and do the procedure described above, I receive after ~2.1 minutes: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET. -> No status code from server

Comment: Are you behind any proxy ? If so try without that. In one of my case proxy was the issue and it was not able to handle request larger than that.

Comment: But shouldn´t the proxy then prevent the file upload in both cases mentioned above? I would expect that it fails in both cases. (without uploading small file first and with uploading small file first) I just double checked, no proxy in use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by myself after a lot of trial and error. I saw that one of my slots in azure app service did not have the issue. It was using another azure function slot. Then I made a diff between my working function slot and my not working function slot. There was one setting which differntiated: Settings -> Configuration -> Common Configuration -> Incoming client certificates

There are two settings you can make:

- Client certificate mode
- Certificate exclusion paths

Client certificate mode was set to '**Allow**' on the function without the issue.
Client certificate mode was set to '**Ignore**' on the function with the issue.

After setting to '**Ignore**' the upload of big files was working without a connection reset. For me it is unclear how this setting can affect a file upload, but it did.

The correct and secure way would be to set certificate mode to '**Required**' and add allowed certificate paths.